# Map an Argument to a list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I want to "map" an argument to a list of functions.

Here is the concrete Problem. I generate a list "Messungfit" of functions:

```
Messungfit = Table[LinearModelFit[Messungenplot[[i]], {1, x}, x], {i, NM}];
```

Now I want to get some more Information from one fit:

```
Messung[[1]]["ParameterTable"]
```

This works perfectly fine.
But what if I want to do this for the whole list. That means Passing the Argument to each function. I tried something like:

```
Messungfit["ParameterTable"]
```

This does not work.

Comment: See [Through](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).

Comment: Try `#["ParameterTable"]&/@Messungfit`?

Comment: Thank you very much. The second one works perfectly. 
But Through does not work. 

      Through[Messungfit, ["ParameterTable"]]

Comment: @mcocdawc, both should work. You need to use: `Through[Messungfit["ParameterTable"]]` or `Through@Messungfit@"ParameterTable"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am quite a beginner.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate; just not sure of what. Anyone?

Comment: @mcocdawc. Please accept the answer below so that we can remove this question from the Unanswered list. I do not receive reputation for the accept because I have posted as a Community Wiki per [this meta post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/answered-but-unanswered-questions-a-self-serving-proposal) and a comment below.

Comment: @march as you say Sir

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  I would have said it's a duplicate of the first example in the docs for [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by `kglr` and `ilian` in the comments, you can do one of two things. We can define a function that you can map over the function, i.e.

```
#["ParameterTable"] &
```

is the pure function that will accept the `Head` of a function, and we map this over the list of function as

```
#["ParameterTable"] & /@ Messungfit
```

Alternatively, we can use `Through`, which is designed to do what the OP is asking, essentially. The correct syntax is

```
Through[Messungfit["ParameterTable"]]
```

or

```
Through @ Messungfit @ "ParameterTable"
```