# Map a list of functions to a number

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

Suppose I have a list of functions like:

```
listfun = { Sin, Cos, Tan }
```

And suppose I want to map `listfun` to a single number `Pi` so that the result is,

```
result = { Sin[Pi], Cos[Pi], Tan[Pi] } = {0, -1, 0}
```

How can I generate `result` above? Thanks!

Comment: Does `Through` fit your needs?

Comment: [(83878)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83878/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Is there a builtin for `#1[##2]&` or similar?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it's been a while since I've used Mathematica and these I've forgotten that such built-in commands are there --- despite I've Googled for so long for such a solution!

Comment: @Szabolcs `#[#2]&` is `Compose` but it won't work with `##2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible ways:

```
listfun = {Sin, Cos, Tan};

Through[listfun[Pi]]
(* {0, -1, 0} *)

#[Pi] & /@ listfun
(* {0, -1, 0} *)
```